# How does numpy determine the array data type when it contains multiple dtypes?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

I am trying to do hands on the numpy, i cam across following datatype when 
used inbuilt method dtype.Following the few results i have got.
Can you please explain what it means by u11

```
a1 = np.array([3,5,'p'])
print(a1.dtype)
```

o/p = >U11

Comment: Have you seen the documentation? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dtype.html#numpy.dtype

Comment: `U11` - a string dtype.  `'p'` can't be turned into a number, so it makes everything else a string to match.

Answer (score 9):

Numpy's array objects that are [`PyArrayObject`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html#c.PyArrayObject) types, have a [`NPY_PRIORITY`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.NPY_PRIORITY) attribute that denotes the priority of the types of items for cases where the array contains items with heterogeneous data types. You can access this priority using  [`PyArray_GetPriority`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_GetPriority) API that returns the [`__array_priority__`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.classes.html#numpy.class.__array_priority__) attribute which according to the the documents:

> `class.__array_priority__` :
> The value of this attribute is used to
> determine what type of object to return in situations where there is
> more than one possibility for the Python type of the returned object.
> Subclasses inherit a default value of 0.0 for this attribute.

Now, in this case Unicode has a higher priority than integer type and that's why `a1.dtype` returns `U11`.

Regarding the `U11` or in general `U#`, you need to note that it consists of two parts; the `U` which denotes a Unicode `dtype` and the `#` shows the number of elements that it can hold --but it can be different in different platforms.

```
In [45]: a1.dtype
Out[45]: dtype('<U21')  # 64bit Linux

In [46]: a1.dtype.type  # The type object used to instantiate a scalar of this data-type. 
Out[46]: numpy.str_

In [49]: a1.dtype.itemsize
Out[49]: 84 # 21 * 4
```

Read more info in greater details about string types and other datatype objects in documentation https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#data-type-objects-dtype.

Comment: Thanks for explanation