# How do I do to concatenate 2 arrays: 1 array contains string and the other array contains int64

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm having a hard time trying to concatenate two arrays using numpy.
One of the arrays have text (`string`) and the other array have numbers (`int64`).

How do I do that?

Using `np.concatenate()` set all the values as string and need both.

I'm running a for loop to determinate the hyperparameters of a `RandomForestClassifier`... when the loop goes to the numbers, gives an error since is expecting the numbers and get the string `'1'` or `'2'`.

I'm using

```
np.concatenate((['auto'], np.arange(20, 120, 20)), axis=0, out=None)
```

and getting

```
array(['auto', '20', '40', '60', '80', '100'], dtype='<U11')
```

However, I need

```
array(['auto', 20, 40, 60, 80, 100])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the arrays you're concatenating should have object dtype in order to get a final array with object type which can hold items with heterogeneous data types:

```
In [7]: np.concatenate((['auto'], np.arange(20, 120, 20).astype(object)), axis=0, out=None)
Out[7]: array(['auto', 20, 40, 60, 80, 100], dtype=object)
```

And if you're wondering how does Numpy determine the array types you can read [How does numpy determin the object-array's dtype and what it means?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751000/how-does-numpy-determin-the-object-arrays-dtype-and-what-it-means/49751834#49751834)

Comment: With `object` dtype you loose a lot of the speed and convenience of working with numeric dtypes.  Such an array is basically a list.  In fact iteration on an equivalent list is faster.

Answer (score 0):

While maybe not being the best solution, this will work:

```py
np.asarray(['auto'] + list(np.arange(20, 120, 20)), dtype=object)
```

Result:

```py
array(['auto', 20, 40, 60, 80, 100], dtype=object)
```

The problem lies in the fact that you are combining different types, and so you need to tell numpy that all objects are allowed as they are, without conversion.