# Why does np.array([1, "a"]) consume Unicode String of 21 characters?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-dtype

When checking the data type of string with one character, i am getting dtype as <U1 as expected.

```
print(numpy.array(["a"]).dtype)

Output : <U1
```

But after adding an integer to the array, why does it consume 21 characters ?

```
print(numpy.array([1,"a"]).dtype)

Output : <U21
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why does it consume 21 characters?

Because the elements are being *promoted*, this means numpy transforms the elements to

> the smallest size and smallest scalar kind to which both type1 and
> type2 may be safely cast.

For example if we use [promote_types](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.promote_types.html):

```
print(np.promote_types('i8', '<U1'))
```

**Output**

```
<U21
```

Regarding the U21, it consists of two parts, as you already know, the U which denotes Unicode and the 21 denotes the number of elements it can hold, see more on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49751834/4001592).

So as *8* can be cast to int64, and it can hold at least 20 characters (platform dependent though), it's being transformed to U21. The know the number of characters a number can have you can do:

```
ii64 = np.iinfo(np.int64)
print(ii64)
```

**Output**

```
Machine parameters for int64
---------------------------------------------------------------
min = -9223372036854775808
max = 9223372036854775807
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

In particular:

```
print(len(str(ii64.min)))
```

**Output**

```
20
```

You can keep U1, by doing:

```
print(np.array(["a", 1]).dtype) # put the string first
```

**Output**

```
<U1
```

See more on this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/7973).